# Use 1 list comprehension instead of 3 to combine two different index searches using Enumerate Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am wondering if it's possible to run through two different enumurate conditions in one list condition:

```
mlist = ['a', 'boy 808', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'a', 'boy 808', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']

loc = [(a,b), a for a, b for b, zip(x in enumerate(mlist), y in enumerate (mlist)) if '808' in x, if 'd' in y]
print(loc)
```

Is this possible? I tried the above and I got invalid syntax error:

```
 File "c:\Users\sys_nsgprobeingestio\Documents\dozie\odfs\ctests.py", line 118
    loc = [(a,b), a for a, b for b, zip(x in enumerate(mlist), y in enumerate (mlist)) if '808' in x, if 'd' in y]
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**I want to get desired ouput: [(1,3), (12,14)]**
**To clarify, this is just a sample array. This logic is to be used in a big file that has multiple occurences of key words. The words here start and end a sections of the file. I wish to get the ordered pair of the head and tail of each section**

A list of ordered tuples of each occurence

**I was able to get what I need using 3 different list comprehensions. I am wondering if you can do it in one**:

```
mlist = ['a', 'boy 808', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'a', 'boy 808', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']

blist = [i for i,x in enumerate(mlist) if 'boy' in x ]
dlist = [i for i,x in enumerate(mlist) if 'd' in x ]

tuplist = [(a,b) for a, b in zip((x for x in blist), (y for y in dlist)) ]
print(tuplist)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply `zip` your `blist` and `dlist` lists:

```
mlist = ['a', 'boy 808', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'a', 'boy 808', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']

tuplist = list(zip([i for i,x in enumerate(mlist) if 'boy' in x],
                   [i for i,x in enumerate(mlist) if 'd' in x]
                  )
              )
print(tuplist)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 3), (12, 14)]
```

You can reduce the comprehensions to 1 by checking for both values at once, if `boy` values are always interleaved with `d` values:

```
dlist = [i for i, x in enumerate(mlist) if 'boy' in x or 'd' in x]
tuplist = list(zip(dlist[::2], dlist[1::2]))
print(tuplist)
```

Comment: I am new to Python. Is this one list comprehension or two zipped to one? I also had no idea you could use zip like that. So thanks for the knowledge

Comment: Well it's really two (one for each enumerate); plus converting a zip object to a list (which is what your `[(a,b) for a, b in zip((x for x in blist), (y for y in dlist)) ]` was doing.

Comment: I see thanks. so 2 lists instead of 3. I'll take that. I don't suppose it would have been possible to do it in 1 at all?

Comment: @edo101 see my edit. As long as your `mlist` always contains `boy`, `d`, `boy`, `d`, etc. you can use a single comprehension to get all the index values and then zip the sub arrays

Comment: tuplist = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(etestlines.index('*Z'), etestlines.index('CONTINUITY'))]  The file contains lines that have the words *Z and CONTINUITY in them but it didn't find it. It kept telling me not in list. SO I opted or enumerate

Comment: @edo101 `index` requires an exact match to the string; that's why it didn't work. Also it will only return the first index of a matching value, not all of them.

Comment: Ah so enumerate is the only viable option. Got it. Thanks. Looks like I will use your method since it's less verbose. Thank you for all the knowledge man. How do I get more knowledgeable? How do you learn more Python?

Comment: Well, you can always read the documentation but the best way IMO is to write code and if you get stuck, ask here. There are many people here who have far greater knowledge of python than I do.